# Uniqueness Of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let there be $V,U$ vector spaces over the same field $F$.

$B=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ a basis for $V$ and $C=(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m)$ a basis for $U$.

If $n=m$ then $T$ a linear transformation is 1-1 and onto (isomorphism)

If $n<m$ then $T$ is can not be 1-1 and onto and therefore it is not unique? because I can choose to send the "remaining" basis vector of $U$ to wherever I want?

Comment: I can probably try to interpret your question... but I think you should try to formulate it in a precise way yourself... so... how do you define $T$? I deduce it is not an arbitrary morphism otherwise you would not ask if it is 1-1 (it could be the $0$ map for example)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unique in either case.
\begin{align}
T(b_1) & = t_{11} c_1 + \cdots + t_{m1}c_m \\
& {}\  \  \vdots \\
T(b_n) & = t_{1n} c_1 + \cdots + t_{mn}c_m
\end{align}
Which linear tranformation this is depends on which scalars $t_{ij}$ are the entries in this $n\times m$ matrix.

Comment: so what does theorem 5.1 here:http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gill/CILASite/Resources/09Chap5.pdf means

Comment: @gbox : That theorem means just what it says.  Notice that it says "such that $T(e_i) = v_i$ for each $i = 1, \ldots , n$.  You didn't include anything like that in your question.  And you were unclear about some other things as well.